# Loop only prints once in text field but works perfectly fine in system print

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to create a program that lists the power and stops at a user input. when I enter text then a for loop in the system it works how it should but when I try to run the same code in a textfeild it only prints the user input number.

```
int n;
n= Integer.parseInt(txtExponent.getText());
for (int i= 0; i <= n; i++) {
txtOutput.setText ("to the power of " +i);
}
```

it outputs "to the power of whatever the user put in instead of to the power of 1, to the power of 2, etc until it reaches the user input

Comment: the code updates the `txtOutput` text in loop and stops at the final text. You probably need to append the text in loop and print , if I understand your question correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append each line of the expected output to a `StringBuilder` and set the same to `txtOutput` once the loop is terminated.

```
int n;
n = Integer.parseInt(txtExponent.getText());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    sb.append("to the power of " + i).append(System.lineSeparator());
}

txtOutput.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the linesperator gives me an error "can not find symbol any suggestions?

Comment: @Mr.Evan - There was a typo which I've corrected now. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue/doubt.

Comment: Thank you for fixing your typo. its still not working because the last line cant be converted to a string

Comment: @Mr.Evan - I've posted another update. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue/doubt.